# Angular js not firing change event on an already checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Please check out this [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ioesandeep/hvakbwhu/). I am getting this weird behaviour from angular on change event on an initially checked chekbox. I checked this using jquery as well. The jquery event fires properly whilst the angular event fires only when the checked is initially unchecked.

Here is my complete code btw:

```
<html ng-app="testing">
<head>
    <title>Angular ng-change test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="ChgCtrl">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="text-info">ng-change</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formElem.checkbox" ng-change="toggleChange(formElem.checkbox)" ng-checked="formElem.checkbox == 1"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>JQuery change event:</h3>
                <P id="jq-messages"></p>
            </div>        
            <div class="col-md-6">                    
                <h3>Angular change event:</h3>
                <p>{{message_change}}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-danger">Please note the first click on checkbox.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('testing', []);
        app.controller('ChgCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.formElem = {
                checkbox: 1
            };
            $scope.message_change = '';

            $scope.toggleChange = function (data) {
                $scope.message_change = data === true ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked';
                console.info(data === true ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked');
            };
        });

        $(function () {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
                $('#jq-messages').html($(this).is(':checked') ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked');
                console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: you should not use ng-checked directive with ng-model , https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `ng-checked` attribute, changed type of `$scope.formElem.checkbox`, corrected if statement `($scope.formElem.checkbox  ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked')`

```js
var app = angular.module('testing', []);
        app.controller('ChgCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.formElem = {
                checkbox: true
            };
            $scope.message_change = '';

            $scope.toggleChange = function (data) {
                $scope.message_change = ($scope.formElem.checkbox  ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked');
                console.info(data === true ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked');
            };
        });

        $(function () {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
                $('#jq-messages').html($(this).is(':checked') ? 'Checked' : 'Unchecked');
                console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
            });
        });
```

```html
<body ng-app="testing">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="ChgCtrl">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="text-info">ng-change</span>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formElem.checkbox" ng-change="toggleChange(formElem.checkbox)" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>JQuery change event:</h3>
                <P id="jq-messages"></p>
            </div>        
            <div class="col-md-6">                    
                <h3>Angular change event:</h3>
                <p>{{message_change}}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-danger">Please note the first click on checkbox.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

`ng-change` event handler, as the name implies, will fire on target value change, but you are just initializing values, not changing them

Comment: Your solution does work. Thank you. The problem with my approach was that I used ng-checked attribute? If that's the case, shouldn't I use it ever?

Comment: You already have `ng-model` attribute, it's a binding, and is smart enough, `ng-checked` is only 1 directional, it will show if value is checked but will not bind it 2 way to the scope

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Also, most ng attributes are named smartly (but there are some exceptions) so `ng-checked` is like `is this checked or not`, just will answer, but if it was named `ng-check`, that would make sense for binding, just take care of those small tips

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure angular - jQuery is not needed.

Remove your `ng-change` and `ng-checked` attributes and just use `ng-model`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formElem.checkbox"/>
```

Then toggle your text with `ng-show` and the model:

```
<p ng-show="formElem.checkbox">checked!</p>
<p ng-show="!formElem.checkbox">not checked.</p>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sgm4bvnb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to use Jquery and do it with all angularJS. Also in controller if you want to see change , use `$scope.$watch`.
Her is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hvakbwhu/8/) .